# FFMPEG - Audio missing after combining video

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, video-processing, tokbox

I was trying to combine two separate video into one side by side using ffmpeg using the following command in ubuntu server.

```
ffmpeg -y -threads 4 -loglevel quiet -ss 0 -t 220.162 -i left.webm 
-ss 0 -t 220.162 -i right.webm -filter_complex "[0]scale=320:-1,pad=2*iw:2*ih:0:120[left];
[1]scale=320:-1[right];[left][right]overlay=main_w/2:120,scale=640:480" -shortest output.mp4
```

The video is processed successfully as expected. But the audio is missing from right.webm. Audio from one video is missing from the output.mp4.
How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is known that in case of some missing audio frames due to network losses, etc., the default opus decoder in ffmpeg may have trouble. Try playing with the following flags with one video, the other one, and composition:

```
ffmpeg -acodec libopus -i filename.webm -ac 2 new_filename.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

The audio is missing because you're only processing the video. I assume you want to mix both audiostreams.
If all you want is to put both videos side by side, then you're better of using [`hstack`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack):

```
ffmpeg -y -threads 4 -loglevel quiet -i left.webm -i right.webm -t 220.162 \
-lavfi hstack;amix -shortest output.mp4
```